# Undefined index user and variable customfunctions

Tags: php, forms

So I get these errors on a custom made website. I am not the developer of it but I have to fix these errors.

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in /var/server/pages/home.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: customFunctions in /var/server/templates/header.tpl on line 44
```

Here's the code of home.php and below that I will attack the header.tpl

```
     <?php
    session_start();    

    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

    if(!is_object($cart)) {
        $cart = new ShoppingCart();
    }


    $user = $_SESSION['user'];

    if(!is_object($user)) {
        $user = new User();
    }


    $mobileDetect = new MobileDetect();
    $deviceType = ($mobileDetect->isMobile() ? ($mobileDetect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
    $bodyClass = '';


    if('computer' == $deviceType) {
        $bodyClass = 'body-computer';
    }
    else {
        $bodyClass = 'home';
    }



    $collectionDb = new CollectionDB();
    $collection = array();

    $collection = $collectionDb->getLastCollection();

    if(!empty($collection)) {
        $collectionTitle = $collection[0]['collection_title_'.$language];
        $collectionImage = $collection[0]['collection_image'];
    }


    require_once('templates/home.tpl');
?>
```

Here's header.tpl code

```
<?php
    $homeLang = '';
    // if('en' == $language) {
    //   $homeLang = $language;
    // }
    $defaultUrl = '';
    $urlVariables = '';

    if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
      $urlVariables .= '/'.$_GET['p'];
    }

    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
      $urlVariables .= '/'.$_GET['id'];
    }

    if(isset($_GET['title'])) {
      $urlVariables .= '/'.$_GET['title'];
    }

    if(isset($_GET['t'])) {
      $urlVariables .= '?t='.$_GET['t'];
    }

    // if(isset($_GET['ord'])) {
    //   $urlVariables .= '&ord='.$_GET['ord'];
    // }

    if(isset($_GET['pg']) && isset($_GET['t'])) {
      $urlVariables .= '&pg='.$_GET['pg'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['pg']) && !isset($_GET['t'])) {
      $urlVariables .= '?pg='.$_GET['pg'];
    }

    //if(!is_object($productCategoryDb)) {
    //  $productCategoryDb = new ProductCategoryDB();
    // }

    if(!is_object($customFunctions)) {
        $customFunctions = new CustomFunctions();
    }

    // $headerProductCategories = $productCategoryDb->getAllProductCategories();
?>

<header <?php if('' == $p) { ?>class="home-header"<?php } ?>>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 hidden-xs">
            <div class="main-menu clearfix">
                <button type="button" id="toggle-menu" class="button-toggle clearfix">
                    <div class="pull-left clearfix">
                        <span class="custom-icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="custom-icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="custom-icon-bar"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="menu-lbl pull-left"><?php echo HEADER_MENU; ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
            <button type="button" id="toggle-menu-xs" class="button-toggle visible-xs">
                <div>
                    <span class="custom-icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="custom-icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="custom-icon-bar"></span>
                </div>
            </button>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="<?php echo SITE_URL.$homeLang; ?>">
                    <?php if('' == $p) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo SITE_ICONS_PATH.'logo.png'; ?>" alt="<?php echo SITE_NAME; ?>">
                    <?php }
                          else {
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo SITE_ICONS_PATH.'logo.png'; ?>" alt="<?php echo SITE_NAME; ?>">
                    <?php } ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <div class="header-account-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="login">
                        <?php if($user->getIsLoggedIn()) { ?>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link login-toggle"><?php echo HEADER_PROFILE; ?></button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu login-dropdown account-dropdown">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $language.'/profile'; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> <?php echo HEADER_ACCOUNT; ?></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $language.'/logout'; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> <?php echo HEADER_SIGN_OUT; ?></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php }
                              else {
                        ?>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link login-toggle"><?php echo HEADER_SIGN_IN; ?></button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu login-dropdown">
                                <!-- <div class="arrow"></div> -->
                                <div class="drop-header">
                                    <span class="text-size16"><?php echo HEADER_SIGN_IN; ?></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="drop-body">
                                    <form id="login-form">
                                        <label for="login-email" class="control-label"><?php echo LOGIN_EMAIL; ?></label>
                                        <input type="email" name="login_email" id="login-email" class="form-control" maxlength="80" placeholder="<?php echo LOGIN_EMAIL; ?>...">
                                        <label for="login-password" class="control-label"><?php echo LOGIN_PASSWORD; ?></label>
                                        <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login-password" class="form-control" maxlength="30" placeholder="<?php echo LOGIN_PASSWORD; ?>...">
                                        <div id="login-error-msg" class="error-msg"><?php echo LOGIN_ERROR; ?></div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="drop-footer">
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                        <ul class="pull-left">
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo $language.'/register'; ?>"><?php echo LOGIN_REGISTER; ?></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo $language.'/passrequest'; ?>"><?php echo LOGIN_FORGOT_PASSWORD; ?></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <button type="button" id="login-btn" class="submit-btn btn btn-default pull-right" name="login_btn" data-loading-text="<?php echo LOGIN_LOADING; ?>..."><?php echo LOGIN_SIGN_IN_BTN; ?></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- end of .dropdown -->
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                    <li class="separator">|</li>
                    <li class="header-cart">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a class="cart-toggle" href="<?php echo $language.'/cart'; ?>">
                                <?php echo HEADER_CART; ?> <span id="header-cart-items"><?php if(0 != count($cart)) { echo '('.count($cart).')'; } ?></span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu cart-dropdown">
                                <div class="arrow"></div>
                                <div class="drop-body"><?php echo PRODUCT_ADDED; ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- end of .dropdown -->
                    </li>
                    <li class="separator">|</li>
                    <li class="header-wishlist">
                        <?php if(!$user->getIsLoggedIn()) { ?>
                                <button id="header-wishlist-popover-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="<?php echo PRODUCT_ADD_WISHLIST_WARNING; ?>"><?php echo HEADER_WISHLIST; ?></button>
                                <?php }
                                      else {
                                ?>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a class="wishlist-toggle" href="<?php echo $language.'/wishlist'; ?>"><?php echo HEADER_WISHLIST; ?></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu wishlist-dropdown">
                                <div class="arrow"></div>
                                <div class="drop-body"><span><?php echo PRODUCT_ITEM_ADDED; ?></span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- end of .dropdown -->
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Smartphone -->
        <div class="hidden" id="mobile-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <?php if('products' == $p && 2 == $_GET['id']) { ?>
                    <span class="active"><?php echo MENU_NEW_ARRIVALS; ?></span>
                    <?php }
                          else {
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $language.'/products/2/new-arrivals'; ?>"><?php echo MENU_NEW_ARRIVALS; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <?php if('products' == $p && 2 != $_GET['id']) { ?>
                    <span class="active"><?php echo MENU_SHOP; ?></span>
                    <?php }
                          else {
                ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $language.'/products/2/new-arrivals'; ?>"><?php echo MENU_SHOP; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <?php if('whats-up' == $p) { ?>
                    <span class="active"><?php echo MENU_WHATS_UP; ?></span>
                    <?php }
                          else {
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $language.'/whats-up'; ?>"><?php echo MENU_WHATS_UP; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <?php if('what-to-wear' == $p) { ?>
                    <span class="active"><?php echo MENU_WHAT_TO_WEAR; ?></span>
                    <?php }
                          else {
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $language.'/what-to-wear'; ?>"><?php echo MENU_WHAT_TO_WEAR; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <?php if('about' == $p) { ?>
                    <span class="active"><?php echo MENU_STORY; ?></span>
                    <?php }
                          else {
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $language.'/about'; ?>"><?php echo MENU_STORY; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="search-form">
                <h3><?php echo MENU_SEARCH; ?></h3>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="searchbox" class="searchbox form-control" maxlength="30" placeholder="enter keywords...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="search-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end of .search-form -->

            <div class="subscribe-link">
                <a href="<?php echo $language.'/subscribe'; ?>"><?php echo MENU_SUBSCRIBE; ?></a>
            </div> <!-- end of .subscribe-form -->
        </div> <!-- end of #mobile-menu -->
</header>
```

Can anyone guide me to the right direction?
I checked out all the posts with this kind of errors on Stackoverflow but i can't find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Adde custom functions class.

```
    <?php
    class CustomFunctions {

        public function greekToGreeklish($string) {
            return strtr($string, array(
                'Α' => 'A', 'Β' => 'V', 'Γ' => 'G', 'Δ' => 'D', 'Ε' => 'E', 'Ζ' => 'Z', 'Η' => 'I', 'Θ' => 'TH', 'Ι' => 'I', 'Κ' => 'K', 'Λ' => 'L',
                'Μ' => 'M', 'Ν' => 'N', 'Ξ' => 'KS', 'Ο' => 'O', 'Π' => 'P', 'Ρ' => 'R', 'Σ' => 'S', 'Τ' => 'T', 'Υ' => 'Y', 'Φ' => 'F', 'Χ' => 'X',
                'Ψ' => 'PS', 'Ω' => 'O',
                'α' => 'a', 'β' => 'v', 'γ' => 'g', 'δ' => 'd', 'ε' => 'e', 'ζ' => 'z', 'η' => 'i', 'θ' => 'th', 'ι' => 'i', 'κ' => 'k', 'λ' => 'l',
                'μ' => 'm', 'ν' => 'n', 'ξ' => 'ks', 'ο' => 'o', 'π' => 'p', 'ρ' => 'r', 'σ' => 's', 'τ' => 't', 'υ' => 'y', 'φ' => 'f', 'χ' => 'x',
                'ψ' => 'ps', 'ω' => 'o', 'ς' => 's', 'ά' => 'a', 'έ' => 'e', 'ή' => 'i', 'ί' => 'i', 'ό' => 'o', 'ύ' => 'y', 'ώ' => 'o', 'ϊ' => 'i',
                'ϋ' => 'y', 'ΐ' => 'i', 'ΰ' => 'y'
            ));
        }

        public function greekLowerToUpper($string) {
            return strtr($string, array(
                'α' => 'Α', 'ά' => 'Α', 'Ά' => 'Α', 'ε' => 'Ε', 'έ' => 'Ε', 'Έ' => 'Ε', 'η' => 'Η', 'ή' => 'Η', 'Ή' => 'Η', 'ι' => 'Ι', 'ί' => 'Ι', 'Ί' => 'Ι', 'ϊ' => 'Ι',
                'ΐ' => 'Ι', 'ο' => 'Ο', 'ό' => 'Ο', 'Ό' => 'Ο', 'υ' => 'Υ', 'ύ' => 'Υ', 'Ύ' => 'Υ', 'ϋ' => 'Υ', 'ΰ' => 'Υ', 'ω' => 'Ω', 'ώ' => 'Ω', 'Ώ' => 'Ω'
            ));
        }

        public function greekToGreekWithoutIntonation($string) {
            return strtr($string, array(
                'Ά' => 'Α', 'ά' => 'α', 'Έ' => 'Ε', 'έ' => 'ε', 'Ή' => 'Η', 'ή' => 'η', 'Ί' => 'Ι', 'ί' => 'ι', 'Ϊ' => 'Ι', 'ϊ' => 'ι', 'ΐ' => 'ι', 'Ό' => 'Ο',
                'ό' => 'ο', 'Ύ' => 'Υ', 'ύ' => 'υ', 'Ϋ' => 'Υ', 'ϋ' => 'υ', 'ΰ' => 'υ', 'Ώ' => 'Ω', 'ώ' => 'ω'
            ));
        }

        public function utf8Urldecode($string) {
            $string = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;", urldecode($string));
            return html_entity_decode($string, null, 'UTF-8');;
        }

        // Generating a seo friendly title
        public function seoUrl($string, $seperator = '-') {         
            $url = str_replace("'", '', $string);
            $url = str_replace('%20', ' ', $url);
            //$url = preg_replace('~[^\\pL0-9_.]+~u', $seperator, $url); // substitutes anything but letters, numbers, '_' and '.' with separator
            $url = preg_replace('~[^\\pL0-9]+~u', $seperator, $url); // substitutes anything but letters, numbers with separator
            $url = trim($url, "-");
            $url = strtolower($url);
            //$url = preg_replace('~[^-a-z0-9_.]+~', '', $url); // keep only letters, numbers, '_', '.' and separator
            $url = preg_replace('~[^-a-z0-9]+~', '', $url); // keep only letters, numbers and separator

            return $url;
        }

        /**
          * Create a web friendly URL slug from a string.
          *
          * Although supported, transliteration is discouraged because
          * 1) most web browsers support UTF-8 characters in URLs
          * 2) transliteration causes a loss of information
          *
          * @author Sean Murphy <sean@iamseanmurphy.com>
          * @copyright Copyright 2012 Sean Murphy. All rights reserved.
          * @license http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/
          **/
        function url_slug($str, $options = array()) {
            // Make sure string is in UTF-8 and strip invalid UTF-8 characters
            $str = mb_convert_encoding((string)$str, 'UTF-8', mb_list_encodings());
            $defaults = array('delimiter' => '-', 'limit' => null, 'lowercase' => true, 'replacements' => array(), 'transliterate' => false);

            // Merge options
            $options = array_merge($defaults, $options);
            $char_map = array(
                // Latin
                'À' => 'A', 'Á' => 'A', 'Â' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A', 'Ä' => 'A', 'Å' => 'A', 'Æ' => 'AE', 'Ç' => 'C',
                'È' => 'E', 'É' => 'E', 'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë' => 'E', 'Ì' => 'I', 'Í' => 'I', 'Î' => 'I', 'Ï' => 'I',
                'Ð' => 'D', 'Ñ' => 'N', 'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó' => 'O', 'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ' => 'O', 'Ö' => 'O', 'Ő' => 'O',
                'Ø' => 'O', 'Ù' => 'U', 'Ú' => 'U', 'Û' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'U', 'Ű' => 'U', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'Þ' => 'TH',
                'ß' => 'ss',
                'à' => 'a', 'á' => 'a', 'â' => 'a', 'ã' => 'a', 'ä' => 'a', 'å' => 'a', 'æ' => 'ae', 'ç' => 'c',
                'è' => 'e', 'é' => 'e', 'ê' => 'e', 'ë' => 'e', 'ì' => 'i', 'í' => 'i', 'î' => 'i', 'ï' => 'i',
                'ð' => 'd', 'ñ' => 'n', 'ò' => 'o', 'ó' => 'o', 'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o', 'ö' => 'o', 'ő' => 'o',
                'ø' => 'o', 'ù' => 'u', 'ú' => 'u', 'û' => 'u', 'ü' => 'u', 'ű' => 'u', 'ý' => 'y', 'þ' => 'th',
                'ÿ' => 'y',

                // Latin symbols
                '©' => '(c)',

                // Greek
                'Α' => 'A', 'Β' => 'B', 'Γ' => 'G', 'Δ' => 'D', 'Ε' => 'E', 'Ζ' => 'Z', 'Η' => 'H', 'Θ' => '8',
                'Ι' => 'I', 'Κ' => 'K', 'Λ' => 'L', 'Μ' => 'M', 'Ν' => 'N', 'Ξ' => '3', 'Ο' => 'O', 'Π' => 'P',
                'Ρ' => 'R', 'Σ' => 'S', 'Τ' => 'T', 'Υ' => 'Y', 'Φ' => 'F', 'Χ' => 'X', 'Ψ' => 'PS', 'Ω' => 'W',
                'Ά' => 'A', 'Έ' => 'E', 'Ί' => 'I', 'Ό' => 'O', 'Ύ' => 'Y', 'Ή' => 'H', 'Ώ' => 'W', 'Ϊ' => 'I',
                'Ϋ' => 'Y',
                'α' => 'a', 'β' => 'b', 'γ' => 'g', 'δ' => 'd', 'ε' => 'e', 'ζ' => 'z', 'η' => 'h', 'θ' => '8',
                'ι' => 'i', 'κ' => 'k', 'λ' => 'l', 'μ' => 'm', 'ν' => 'n', 'ξ' => '3', 'ο' => 'o', 'π' => 'p',
                'ρ' => 'r', 'σ' => 's', 'τ' => 't', 'υ' => 'y', 'φ' => 'f', 'χ' => 'x', 'ψ' => 'ps', 'ω' => 'w',
                'ά' => 'a', 'έ' => 'e', 'ί' => 'i', 'ό' => 'o', 'ύ' => 'y', 'ή' => 'h', 'ώ' => 'w', 'ς' => 's',
                'ϊ' => 'i', 'ΰ' => 'y', 'ϋ' => 'y', 'ΐ' => 'i',

                // Turkish
                'Ş' => 'S', 'İ' => 'I', 'Ç' => 'C', 'Ü' => 'U', 'Ö' => 'O', 'Ğ' => 'G',
                'ş' => 's', 'ı' => 'i', 'ç' => 'c', 'ü' => 'u', 'ö' => 'o', 'ğ' => 'g',

                // Russian
                'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G', 'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'Yo', 'Ж' => 'Zh',
                'З' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I', 'Й' => 'J', 'К' => 'K', 'Л' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'О' => 'O',
                'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T', 'У' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F', 'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'C',
                'Ч' => 'Ch', 'Ш' => 'Sh', 'Щ' => 'Sh', 'Ъ' => '', 'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'Yu',
                'Я' => 'Ya',
                'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo', 'ж' => 'zh',
                'з' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'j', 'к' => 'k', 'л' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'о' => 'o',
                'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'т' => 't', 'у' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c',
                'ч' => 'ch', 'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sh', 'ъ' => '', 'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu',
                'я' => 'ya',

                // Ukrainian
                'Є' => 'Ye', 'І' => 'I', 'Ї' => 'Yi', 'Ґ' => 'G',
                'є' => 'ye', 'і' => 'i', 'ї' => 'yi', 'ґ' => 'g',

                // Czech
                'Č' => 'C', 'Ď' => 'D', 'Ě' => 'E', 'Ň' => 'N', 'Ř' => 'R', 'Š' => 'S', 'Ť' => 'T', 'Ů' => 'U',
                'Ž' => 'Z',
                'č' => 'c', 'ď' => 'd', 'ě' => 'e', 'ň' => 'n', 'ř' => 'r', 'š' => 's', 'ť' => 't', 'ů' => 'u',
                'ž' => 'z',

                // Polish
                'Ą' => 'A', 'Ć' => 'C', 'Ę' => 'e', 'Ł' => 'L', 'Ń' => 'N', 'Ó' => 'o', 'Ś' => 'S', 'Ź' => 'Z',
                'Ż' => 'Z',
                'ą' => 'a', 'ć' => 'c', 'ę' => 'e', 'ł' => 'l', 'ń' => 'n', 'ó' => 'o', 'ś' => 's', 'ź' => 'z',
                'ż' => 'z',

                // Latvian
                'Ā' => 'A', 'Č' => 'C', 'Ē' => 'E', 'Ģ' => 'G', 'Ī' => 'i', 'Ķ' => 'k', 'Ļ' => 'L', 'Ņ' => 'N',
                'Š' => 'S', 'Ū' => 'u', 'Ž' => 'Z',
                'ā' => 'a', 'č' => 'c', 'ē' => 'e', 'ģ' => 'g', 'ī' => 'i', 'ķ' => 'k', 'ļ' => 'l', 'ņ' => 'n',
                'š' => 's', 'ū' => 'u', 'ž' => 'z'
            );

            // Make custom replacements
            $str = preg_replace(array_keys($options['replacements']), $options['replacements'], $str);

            // Transliterate characters to ASCII
            if ($options['transliterate']) {
                $str = str_replace(array_keys($char_map), $char_map, $str);
            }

            // Replace non-alphanumeric characters with our delimiter
            $str = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]+/u', $options['delimiter'], $str);

            // Remove duplicate delimiters
            $str = preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($options['delimiter'], '/') . '){2,}/', '$1', $str);

            // Truncate slug to max. characters
            $str = mb_substr($str, 0, ($options['limit'] ? $options['limit'] : mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8')), 'UTF-8');

            // Remove delimiter from ends
            $str = trim($str, $options['delimiter']);

            return $options['lowercase'] ? mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8') : $str;
        }

        /* Validate an email address. */
        function emailValidate($sToEmail, $sFromDomain = "yourdomain.com", $sFromEmail = "sample@yourdomain.com", $bIsDebug = false) {
            $bIsValid = true; // assume the address is valid by default..
            $aEmailParts = explode("@", $sToEmail); // extract the user/domain..
            getmxrr($aEmailParts[1], $aMatches); // get the mx records..

            if(sizeof($aMatches) == 0) {
                return false; // no mx records..
            }

            foreach ($aMatches as $oValue) {
                if($bIsValid && !isset($sResponseCode)) {
                    // open the connection..
                    $oConnection = @fsockopen($oValue, 25, $errno, $errstr, 30);
                    $oResponse = @fgets($oConnection);

                    if(!$oConnection) {
                        $aConnectionLog['Connection'] = "ERROR";
                        $aConnectionLog['ConnectionResponse'] = $errstr;
                        $bIsValid = false; // unable to connect..
                    }
                    else {
                        $aConnectionLog['Connection'] = "SUCCESS";
                        $aConnectionLog['ConnectionResponse'] = $errstr;
                        $bIsValid = true; // so far so good..
                    }

                    if(!$bIsValid) {
                        if($bIsDebug) print_r($aConnectionLog);
                        return false;
                    }

                    // say hello to the server..
                    fputs($oConnection, "HELO $sFromDomain\r\n");
                    $oResponse = fgets($oConnection);
                    $aConnectionLog['HELO'] = $oResponse;

                    // send the email from..
                    fputs($oConnection, "MAIL FROM: <$sFromEmail>\r\n");
                    $oResponse = fgets($oConnection);
                    $aConnectionLog['MailFromResponse'] = $oResponse;

                    // send the email to..
                    fputs($oConnection, "RCPT TO: <$sToEmail>\r\n");
                    $oResponse = fgets($oConnection);
                    $aConnectionLog['MailToResponse'] = $oResponse;

                    // get the response code..
                    $sResponseCode = substr($aConnectionLog['MailToResponse'], 0, 3);
                    $sBaseResponseCode = substr($sResponseCode, 0, 1);

                    // say goodbye..
                    fputs($oConnection,"QUIT\r\n");
                    $oResponse = fgets($oConnection);

                    // get the quit code and response..
                    $aConnectionLog['QuitResponse'] = $oResponse;
                    $aConnectionLog['QuitCode'] = substr($oResponse, 0, 3);

                    if($sBaseResponseCode == "5") {
                        $bIsValid = false; // the address is not valid..
                    }

                    // close the connection..
                    @fclose($oConnection);
                }
            }

            if ($bIsDebug) {
                print_r($aConnectionLog); // output debug info..
            }

            return $bIsValid;
        }


        // Limit the words of display
        public function limitWords($string, $limit) {
            $words = explode(" ", $string);
            return implode(" ", array_splice($words, 0, $limit));
        }

        public function rrmdir($directory, $empty=false) {
            // if the path has a slash at the end we remove it here
            if(substr($directory,-1) == '/') {
                $directory = substr($directory,0,-1);
            }

            // if the path is not valid or is not a directory ...
            if(!file_exists($directory) || !is_dir($directory)) {
                // ... we return false and exit the function
                return false;

                // ... if the path is not readable
            }
            else if(!is_readable($directory)) {
                // ... we return false and exit the function
                return false;

                // ... else if the path is readable
            }
            else {
                // we open the directory
                $handle = opendir($directory);

                // and scan through the items inside
                while (false !== ($item = readdir($handle))) {
                    // if the filepointer is not the current directory
                    // or the parent directory
                    if($item != '.' && $item != '..') {
                        // we build the new path to delete
                        $path = $directory.'/'.$item;

                        // if the new path is a directory
                        if(is_dir($path))  {
                            // we call this function with the new path
                            rrmdir($path);

                            // if the new path is a file
                        }
                        else {
                            // we remove the file
                            unlink($path);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // close the directory
                closedir($handle);

                // if the option to empty is not set to true
                if($empty == false) {
                    // try to delete the now empty directory
                    if(!rmdir($directory)) {
                        // return false if not possible
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                // return success
                return true;
            }
        }

        public function stringReplaceChar($string, $character, $newCharacter) {
            $newString = str_replace($character, $newCharacter, $string);

            return $newString;
        }

        public function randomString($length) {
            //$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            $str = '';

            $size = strlen($chars);

            for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $str .= $chars[rand(0, $size - 1)];
            }

            return $str;
        }

        public function array_values_recursive($array) {
            $flat = array();

            foreach ($array as $value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    $flat = array_merge($flat, $this->array_values_recursive($value));
                }
                else {
                    $flat[] = $value;
                }
            }

            return $flat;
        }

        public function searchByKeyValue($array, $key, $value) {
            $results = array();

            if(is_array($array)) {
                if(isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
                    $results[] = $array;
                }

                foreach($array as $subarray) {
                    $results = array_merge($results, $this->searchByKeyValue($subarray, $key, $value));
                }
            }

            return $results;
        }

        // Email format validation
        public function emailValidation($email) {
            $isValid = true;

            if(empty($email) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $isValid = false;
            }

            return $isValid;
        }

        public function fixHttpUrl($url) {
            $newUrl = "";
            $urlPrefix = "http://";
            $pos = strpos($url, $urlPrefix);

            if ($pos === false) {
                $newUrl = $urlPrefix.$url;
            } else {
                $newUrl = $url;
            }

            return $newUrl;
        }

        public function get_ip_address() {
            foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key) {
                if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {
                    foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {
                        if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false) {
                            return $ip;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Get video image thumbnail
        public function getVideoThumbUrl($url) {
            $videoThumbUrl = '';

            if (strpos($url, 'youtube') !== false) {
                $tempArray = explode('v=', $url);
                $tempArray = explode('&', $tempArray[1]);
                $videoThumbUrl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$tempArray[0].'/0.jpg';
            }

            if (strpos($url, 'vimeo') !== false) {
                $tempArray = explode('.com/', $url);
                $hash = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$tempArray[1].'.php'));
                $videoThumbUrl = $hash[0]['thumbnail_large'];
            }

            if (strpos($url, 'dailymotion') !== false) {
                $tempArray = explode('video/', $url);
                $videoThumbUrl = 'http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/'.$tempArray[1];
            }

            return $videoThumbUrl;
        }

        // Change the date format
        public function formatDate($date) {
            $newDate = date('j.n.Y', strtotime($date));

            return $newDate;
        }

        public function formatDateWithHour($date) {
            $newDate = date('j M Y H:i:s', strtotime($date));

            return $newDate;
        }

        public function formatDateToString($date) {
            $newDate = date('l, j F Y', strtotime($date));

            return $newDate;
        }

        public function formatDateMonthYear($date) {
            $newDate = date('M Y', strtotime($date));

            return $newDate;
        }

        public function mysqlFormatDate($date) {
            $newDate = date('Y-m-d '.date(" H:i:s", time()), strtotime($date));

            return $newDate;
        }

        public function reverseMysqlFormatDate($date) {
            $newDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));

            return $newDate;
        }

        public function getAgeFromBirthdate($date) {
            $givenDate = new DateTime($date);
            $currentDate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
            $age = $givenDate->diff($currentDate);

            return $age->format('%y');
        }

        public function __destruct() {
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: The code you posted is totally irrelevant. See what error says, and show us your home.php first 15 lines: `/var/server/pages/home.php on line 13`

Comment: ...and `header.tpl`'s first 50...

Comment: and where is this come from? `if(!is_object($customFunctions)) {` it seems `$customFunctions` is not initialized.

Comment: first error is about some included file

Comment: @lolka_bolka you're right, i updated the home.php file on the main post and i'll add the customfunctions class right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the worst router I have seen in my whole life...
for the error in header.tpl try replacing

```
if(!is_object($customFunctions)) {
        $customFunctions = new CustomFunctions();
    }
```

by

```
if(!isset($customFunctions)||!is_object($customFunctions)) {
        $customFunctions = new CustomFunctions();
    }
```

for the error in home, I have no clue...

Comment: it seems to be fixed. should i do !isset on all the files that have this kind of code?

Comment: I can't help you more, I don't know how those variables are set and so if they can be undefined...